# How can I get a user input from Excel in R dynamically?

Tags: r, excel, vba, rexcel

I'm using Excel to call a script in R.
R eventually generates a graph, on the basis of which I want the user to be able to see and give an input.
Is there any way to get an input into R from Excel during runtime?

Thanks

Comment: While I understand that this is a question about Excel, have you considered a Shiny app for something like this?

Comment: I'd love to know how you call R from Excel.  Are you using one of the packages available online when you google "how to call R from Excel" (such as RExcel or BERT), or are you calling some kind of R batch file from VBA?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution.
I ran a shell script that called a vbs that invoked a different workbook that ran a vba code that called the original workbook I wanted to work with while R checked the contents of the new workbook until they were changed(which is when the input box was filled in the original workbook).